# Could not load file or assembly 'WPF.MDI, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Using WPF.MDI dll from [codeplex](http://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/) in my wpf project I am getting this error when I run the project:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'WPF.MDI, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. A strongly-named assembly is required. 
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044)":"WPF.MDI, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

I discovered it happens when I add name to the `MdiContainer`:

```
 <mdi:MdiContainer Theme="Aero" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="0 20 0 0" Name="MainMdiContainer">
```

But I need the name to call the child into the `MdiContainer`.

Comment: If you don't name it, it loads fine?

Comment: yes, it loads fine.